# ant sql task: complex CLOB content leads to exception

Tags: java, sql, oracle, ant, sqlplus

Being a database user rather than a database programmer, I find the following situation quite strange. Maybe someone can shed some light here?

Task: track sql script execution in a database table (below: history_table) using an ant script which takes the sql script, executes it and puts the executed script into the history table. This works so far (e.g. with a one liner sql script, such as 'select sysdate from dual;'), but with more complex content in the sql script, there are errors thrown. The following sample code should explain the problem.

the table:

```
create table history_table (
    case_nr varchar2(20) not null,
    sql_data clob not null
)
```

the ant task:

```
<target name="put_into_history_table">

    <loadfile property="script_content.raw" srcFile="${script}" />

    <sql
        classpath="./ojdbc6.jar"
        driver="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@${db.hostname}:${db.port}:${db.sid}" 
        userid="${db.user}" 
        password="${db.password}"
        expandproperties="true">

insert  into history_table (case_nr, file_content)
        values ('${case.nr}', to_clob('${script_content.raw}');
commit;

    </sql>

</target>
```

the script.sql

```
select *
from some_table
where (
    name is not null
    and
    condition = 'T'
);
```

the result, a.k.a. exception:

```
$ ant
Buildfile: D:\temp\scripts\build.xml

put_into_history_table:
      [sql] Executing commands
      [sql] Failed to execute:
      [sql] insert      into history_table (case_nr, file_content)
      [sql]             values ('case123', to_clob('select *
      [sql] from some_table
      [sql] where (
      [sql]     name is not null
      [sql]     and
      [sql]     condition = 'T'
      [sql] );
      [sql]
      [sql] '));
      [sql] commit;

BUILD FAILED
D:\temp\scripts\build.xml:48: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

...
Total time: 0 seconds

$
```

I'm not sure, where I miss something. Imho the clob should be treated as bulk of characters and not be interpreted in any way.
(Maybe of inportance: ant version: 1.9.2; java version 1.8.0_31; oracle version 11.2.0.1.0)
Any help or explanation is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error states "Missing right parenthesis" , probably from here :

```
select *
from some_table
where (
    name is not null
    and
    condition = 'T'
};
```

"}" should be a parenthesis.

As stated in the discussion below, the exception is really caused by **insufficient escaping of quotes** that appear in the script.sql.

Comment: What a blind mole have I been! You are right, of course. However, this does lead to the next problem. I will update the question accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: "next problem" means "same problem". I have corrected the statement in the script.sql, it's executable in Oracle SQL Developer. Still, from the ant script, I get the same exception.

Comment: Does the query work when you execute it ? insert  into history_table (case_nr, file_content)
 values ('case123', to_clob('select * from some_table  where (  name is not null  and condition = 'T' );'));

Comment: Correct question. In Oracle SQL Developer, it does not. When I escape the quote characters (in 'T') with '', then it works. However, if I do the same in the script.sql file, it ends up in a "ORA-00911: Invalid character". Think, I have to find a way to properly escape the quotes in the file.So you pointed me to the right direction, the quotes seem to be the origin of problems.